# C# WPF WebBrowser Multi Touch

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, web, touch

Hopefully someone can help, I'm having a few issues embedding a web browser into my application to display a Google maps page.

The page loads correctly in the IE Web browser and Awesomium, However we are actually using a Windows 7 touch screen and if I pinch zoom the Google Map the whole web browser zooms in. It doesn't seem to invoke the touch event on the Google Map.

If I browse to Google Maps via IE or Chrome the map support multi touch gestures, using the chrome.exe or ieexplorer.exe (not embedding in the application).

Is it possible to embed the same functionality into a WPF application?

Comment: I've made the IE Web Browser Control work correctly by forcing it to use IE9. I've added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" > to the header in the HTML file.

But still stuck on Aweomium...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GekoFX seems to support the touch events.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider [DotNetBrowser](http://teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser) as an alternative. Its heavyweight mode provides support for touch events, and the Google Maps tutorial is available on C# Corner: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/embed-google-maps-in-net-desktop-application/